# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app  when I tried to build it an error came up

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you have AVfoundation.framework added to your linked binaries?

Comment: @Jay I did add the AVFoundation.framework to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", is that what you are asking.

Comment: Have you added `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` or `@import AVFoundation;`?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I did that too, because I was frustrated with this, I copied all of the code into a new project, and no longer received the error, and the app works just fine in the new project.

Comment: there was a lot of junk logs